# How to group GUI components in an array Java

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, for-loop

Specifically I want to put several labels in an array so I can easily search them using a for-loop, like I have been doing with non-GUI programming like this:

```
//finds a string in an array
public static int StringSearch(String lookFor, String[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (lookFor.equalsIgnoreCase(array[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}//end string search
```

Is there a way to do something similar to this in GUI?

Comment: Yes, it works the same way for every object

Comment: could you provide an example of how to make an array with GUI objects?

Comment: `JLabel labels[] = new JLabel[10];` ... just like you would for an array of objects

Comment: @MadProgrammer You could turn your comment to an answer. It did help me.